# problem debugging springboot mongodb api implementation

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

Working on someone else's implementation of mongodb springboot apis and the POST method for adding a new record. The issue is that the fields for the object need to be renamed but for some reason the POST body has a couple fields that have some built-in validation that does not allow me to rename the fields. An example will better illustrate this:
the body to be submitted with a POST

```
{
  "clientId": 101,
  "url":   "https://www.google.com",
  "dateAdded": "2023-07-06"
 }
```

now the dto class validates that the fields should not be null or empty. I just changed the name of the url field because the original name in the database is websiteUrl. I then made sure the dto class also reflects that name change as well as in the object class that accepts this new record:

```
 @NotBlank(message = "The url is required.")
private String websiteUrl; //{changed from} private String url;
private String projectId;
```

now the problem is that despite these changes; when submitting a POST with the body showing the updated fields, the response error is "the url is required". It seems to be built in somewhere to expect a field named 'url' somewhere and I cannot find that reference. The repository interface method called is as follows:

```
public interface WebsiteRepository extends MongoRepository<website, String>{

List<website> findByClientAndUrl(
   String clientId,  String url);
}
```

Is it possible that this field 'url' is required and enforced somewhere. Changing the name of the field in the body, dto and object should not cause this simple POST method to fail.

EDIT:  stacktrace included; field was renamed in both .dto and model object.

```
"org.springframework.data.mapping.context.InvalidPersistentPropertyPath: No property 'url' found on class com.example.demo.model.premium_lite; Did you mean: url\n\tat org.springframework.data.mapping.context.PersistentPropertyPathFactory.createPersistentPropertyPath(PersistentPropertyPathFactory.java:204)\n\tat org.springframework.data.mapping.context.PersistentPropertyPathFactory.lambda$getPersistentPropertyPath$1(PersistentPropertyPathFactory.java:171)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentMap.java:330)\n\tat
```

Comment: Can you share the full error message? Is it a stack trace that can point us towards a line of code (if so, share that context too)? Or is the message a passthrough from, for example, database validation failing?